# Magento 2 Modal Pop up from exception

Tags: magento2, checkout, event-observer, modal-popup

I have an observer that rejects this save of orders conditionally and throws a message. Instead of the message I would like to trigger a modal. How can I get this done?

```
$message = “We were unable to verify your age.”;
throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException(__($message));
return;
```